# No option to click on list items to open form

Tags: sharepoint-server, list

I just created a list and I don't have the option to click on any of the rows to open the form view. How can I enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Select the item, in the ribbon, click list tab, then click From Web Parts.

[image]